# Python - Incorrect print of the day of the week

Tags: python

Below I have a code that should ask the user to enter a day of the month. We will assume the month starts on Monday and has 31 days. If the day of the month the user entered is not a valid day of the month (less than 1 or greater than 31), print "Invalid day". Otherwise print the day of the week that day falls on.

For instance, the second would be a Tuesday, the 10th would be a Wednesday, etc.

The Problem I am having is that it keeps on printing Wednesday whenever I input any number in the week. If I enter the 1st it should print Monday and if i input the 2nd it should print out Tuesday and so forth until i enter the 31st.

I want to figure out what why it's displaying only Wednesday.

```
#Description: Ask user to enter a day in the month.
#The dayof the month can not be less than 1 
#or greater than 31 or it's invalid.

#Enter the day of the week
#Description: Ask user to enter a day in the month.
#The dayof the month can not be less than 1 
#or greater than 31 or it's invalid.


DayofMonth = int(input("Enter the day of the month: "))

if DayofMonth >= 1 and DayofMonth <= 31:    
    days = ["Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday", "Sunday"] 
    DayofMonth = 31
    dx = DayofMonth + 1 
    #print (days [dx % 7]) 


    print("The day of the week is: ", days [dx % 7])
else:
    print("Invalid day")
```

Comment: I was fixing it for a while and it finally accepted the format but it looked different from what is posted when i originally submitted it.

Comment: i've fixed it now it read better

Comment: And by the way, it should always print Friday according to this error.

Answer (score 1):

That's because you assign `DayofMonth` to the hardcoded value of 31 right after accepting input:

```
DayofMonth = int(input("Enter the day of the month: "))

if DayofMonth >= 1 and DayofMonth <= 31:
    days = ["Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday", "Sunday"] 


    dx = DayofMonth + 1 # omitted extra line 
    print("The day of the week is: ", days [dx % 7])
```

Comment: yes, I realized that when i took another look at it but thanks for the clarification.

Comment: If you could mark as answer, that would be much appreciated.